# Password Matcher in DotNet Core

Tags: .net-core, passwords, compare, asp.net-identity, password-encryption

I am working on project in `.Net Core 5.`
I am storing all recent `passwords (hashed value of course)` used by a user, in a details table (Master-Detail format). I am storing those passwords to prevent the user to use an old password, he/she used already.
Now how can I compare a plain text password, that user has just submitted with the hashed passwords those are saved in Database.
In NodeJS, we usually use `Becrypt` package and use `compare` method to compare plaintext and hashed ones.
Is there any methods available in .Net Core, that I can use like `Compare` function to check if inputted password is already stored in Database.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following to verify each of the old hashed passwords against the new password.

```
UserManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedPassword, rawNewPassword)
```

Further details for .Net Core 5 can be found - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1.verifyhashedpassword?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
I actually implement this using `VerifyHashedPassword (TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)` mehotd.
The details I found on this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordhasher-1.verifyhashedpassword?view=aspnetcore-5.0